# Just see debugging application ouput in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a simple Android app using Android Studio for Linux, I'm debugging the app in my Android phone (Huawei Y300). The thing is, in the output I see information about dalvik, signal strength and some other stuff that I don't want to see.

Is there a way to just see the output of the debugging app?

Comment: have you tried logcat?

Comment: @nr4bt isn't that logcat?

Comment: I wasn't sure what you were using, you can filter logcat output by using package name or other filter criterias, in that way, you'll only see your app output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using LogCat, I'd recommend using a filter. You can do this by either right-clicking one of the log lines of your app and pressing `Find similar messages...` or by following these steps:

1. Press `+` in the `Saved Filters` section to the left of LogCat.
2. Add a filter name
3. Either your desired TAG or Application name
4. Press `OK`